# Pure greedy algorithm

Tags: functional-analysis, algorithms

I study pure greedy algorithms in different basises. I am interested in 1 one question: is there such a Riesz basis $D$ in Hilbert space and $f\in H$ such that
$$||f-G_m(f,D)||>Cm^{-1/2}|f|_{H}$$ for some constant $C$
i.e. convergence rate is bigger than $-1/2$?
I know that there are such dictionaries that CR is bigger than $-1/2$( even $-0.27$) but I can not construct such a Riesz basis.
 My steps, that might be helpful.There is a theorem that if $$\sup_{g\in D }\sum_{g'\in D,g'\not=g}|\langle g,g'\rangle|<1/3 $$ than convergence rate is less than $-1/2$.That is why I took Riesz basis for  which that supremum equal to 1: $$ D=(f_j), f_j=e_j+\frac{1}{2}e_{j+1}$$
Now I want to find $f$. But I can not :(

Comment: What is $A_1(D)$?

Comment: I added it, sorry that is was not clear

Comment: $G_m(f,D)$ is approximant that we obtain at $m$th step of pure greedy algorithm